# expected unqualified-id before '{' token c++

Tags: c++

I'm facing titled problem in my assignment at line 60. Please anyone help me as quick as possible.

```
59 void storeFile();
60 {
61 cout<< "All the data members are stored in file." << endl;
62 
63 ofstream outFile;
64 const char *outputFileName = ("record.txt");
65 outFile.open(outputFileName, ios::out);
66 
67 if(!outFile)
68 {
69      cout<< "\nUnable to open the file." << outputFileName << endl;
70      }
71 
72      else
73          {
74              outFile VUID; endl;
75              outFile campusID; endl;
76              outFile studentName; endl;
77              outFile fatherName; endl;
78                  }
79 };
```

error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token c++ at line 60

Comment: remove the last semicolon on line 59

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typewriting.


Comment: I can't figure out how a quick Google search about that exact error didn't reply to your question...

Comment: And now I just looked to the right... -_-' I don't want to live in this planet anymore...

Comment: I removed ; from the line 59 but now facing error at line 74 column 13 [Error] expected ';' before 'VUID'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404547/c-programming-error-expected-unqualified-id-before-token for some good pointers, at least regarding your original issue, you can probably find more here on so...

Comment: ..btw - it appears you're taking the same class... ask your classmate instead.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314497/cannot-write-the-data-in-the-file-no-error-in-the-program-c

Answer (score 9):

Remove the `;` at the end of line 59.

By the way, as ChrisCM and U2CO3 have written, the `;` at end of line 79 is not needed, even if that one does not generate a compilation error.

Comment: The one at line 79 is also unnecessary.

Comment: @H2CO3 ChrisCM's comment was about 10 seconds before yours :D

Comment: @PhilipKendall I was writing mine :D

Comment: All is fair in love and the grabbing of obvious stackoverflow answers.

Comment: @H2CO3 there's no shame in that... Don't hate the playa, hate the game... :D

Comment: I removed ; from the line 59 but now facing error at line 74 column 13 [Error] expected ';' before 'VUID'

Comment: @TiroSagacious You'll have to find some teaching resource about how to use C++ `ostream` objects. Try `outFile << VUID << endl;` for immediate result.

Comment: @TiroSagacious You should really try to understand what you are coding instead of copy-pasting something that doesn't make any sense. `outFile` is a `ofstream` type variable, and I imagine that `VUID` is also some type of variable - so what happens in C++ if you write 2 variable names next to each other?

Answer (score 2):

It seems mistakenly it was added a `;` at line 59

```
void storeFile();
```

Replace it with

```
void storeFile()
```

Comment: I removed ; from the line 59 but now facing error at line 74 column 13 [Error] expected ';' before 'VUID'

Answer (score 1):

And probably delete the one on line 79 too.